# What is the idiomatic way to implement long running jobs in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a jenkins declarative pipeline job which invokes a [shared library](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/). The groovy script in the library executes a couple of quick commands and then polls for the result (with `Thread.sleep()`) which could take up to 10 minutes. However after 5 minutes the thread is interrupted, which is [by design](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/pull/313/files). The discussion in the previous link mentions that such workloads should be done

> in a step so it can happen on a background thread rather than holding up this thread

But it's not clear what is implied here. The shared library code is invoked from a `script` block inside a step.

Comment: Why not using `sleep()` utility step?

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` is called from a third party lib linked via `@Grab` in the groovy script.

Comment: If third-party library is using some functionality that is rejected by Jenkins "by design", I don't see any way out except not using that third-party library.

Comment: (Why) Is it strictly necessary to run this in the shared libraray?

Answer (score 0):

In theory a while loop that only exits when the program receives the correct signal that jenkins sends when you click stop should work. But jenkins seems like the wrong tool to manage a long running process, I would look into systemd or other OS level init system so I could pass the responsibility of keeping the process running onto my ops team.